# illegal initializer for char — how to fix?

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I want to specify print characters, but I had an error here. What should I do? (See my code) I'm just self taught in Java... almost a month now.

```
public class l2{
public static void main(String[] args){

    char table = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},{'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'},{'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'},{'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'}};
    final int rowSize = 4;
    final int columnSize = 4;
    String[][] a = new String[rowSize][columnSize];
    // iterate
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnSize; column++) {
            a[row][column] = Char.valueOf(ar.charAt(rowSize * row + column));
        }
    }
    // test
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnSize; column++) {
            System.out.print(a[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The errors are:

> ```
> l2.java:4: error: illegal initializer for char
> char table = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},{'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'},{'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'},{'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'}};
>
> l2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol Char[][] a = new Char[rowSize][columnSize];
> ^ symbol: class Char location: class l2
> l2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol Char[][] a = new Char[rowSize][columnSize];
> ^ symbol: class Char location: class l2
> l2.java:11: error: cannot find symbol a[row][column] = Char.valueOf(ar.charAt(rowSize * row + column));
> ```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: here is the error

l2.java:4: error: illegal initializer for char
        char table = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},{'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'},{'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'},{'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'}};
                     ^

Comment: and this one...

l2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    Char[][] a = new Char[rowSize][columnSize];
    ^
  symbol:   class Char
  location: class l2
l2.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    Char[][] a = new Char[rowSize][columnSize];
                     ^
  symbol:   class Char
  location: class l2
l2.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            a[row][column] = Char.valueOf(ar.charAt(rowSize * row + column));

Comment: Can you please clearly describe what is the goal of this program?

Comment: You need to declare char array as `char[][] table`. There are other errors as well `Char.valueOf(ar` - what is Char here ? There is no class in java called `char`, do you mean `Character` ? What is `ar`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry my bad.. I'm just new on java... I just want to create a 4 x 4 array of type char and input the values from a 16-character String. Output also the transverse of this array where the row and column indexes for each element are interchanged... 

nevermid the 'ar' it's 'table' -- corect me if im wrong

Comment: Kindly edit your post with clarifications. Do not add those in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to print 'table A B ...' in output, you can do this:

```
public class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] table = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}, {'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'}, {'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'}, {'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'}};
        final int rowSize = 4;
        final int columnSize = 4;
        
        for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columnSize; column++) {
                System.out.print(table[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

### output:

```
A B C D 
E F G H 
I J K L 
M N O P
```